# SSL/TLS1.0 support through code

Tags: firefox-addon, ssl

I want to develop one Add-on/extension, which will communicate with one server over TCP socket. I want to make this communication secure by using SSL or TLS.

Is there any way to use SSL/TLS implementation from Mozilla Firefox? Is there any kind of protocols available to perform SSL/TLS actions in Firefox?

Vishal N

Answer (score 0):

The socket transport service can be used to [create](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XPCOM_Interface_Reference/nsISocketTransportService#createTransport%28%29) a TLS or SSL socket.